# Have we ever seen an African-American version of this character in the comics?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, superman-and-lois

In *Season 1: Episode 1* of the new CW's show *Superman & Lois*, we see that an unknown assailant in a mech-suit is trying to kill Superman. The assailant is later revealed to be:

> An African-American version of **Lex Luthor** (or *Captain Luthor*) who is either from 
>     - an alternate universe/reality, or, 
>     - the future

Has there been an African-American version of this character in the comics?

Comment: He was quite dark-skinned in the animated series; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oF3R-ymIYeo

Comment: @Valorum I assumed that was because he spent a lot of time getting kryptonite radiation baths :p :p

Comment: Word-of-god is that he was based on Telly Savalas (e.g. he's 'olive-skinned')

Comment: By now, it has been revealed that the character referenced in this question who attacked Superman was not who we originally were led to believe, but is in fact a different character who _is_ portrayed in the comics as an African-American.

Answer (score 6):

### As far as I know, Luthor has never been depicted as a black man in the comics.

I checked [his disambiguation page](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Lex_Luthor) at dc.fandom.com to make sure, and couldn't see a black version of Luthor from the comics there.

In general, the changing of a character's race (even in alternate universes) seems to be less of a thing in superhero comics than it is in other media.

---

Luthor was, however, ostensibly depicted as black in the [*Harley Quinn* TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn_(TV_series)).

[image]

Aside from how he was drawn and coloured, he was also voiced by a black actor, Giancarlo Esposito, who appears to confirm that his version of Luthor was indeed black in the video interview below:

This is also confirmed by the following statement from the *Harley Quinn* showrunners (Justin Halpern and Patrick Schumacker), made in [an email sent to Collider](https://collider.com/harley-quinn-lex-luthor-giancarlo-esposito-interview/):

> But Halpern and Schumacker say that *Harley Quinn* "does conceive of Lex Luthor to be a person of color. We're not sure if we are the first to make Lex a POC, but DC was supportive when we said we wanted to go in that direction, which was cool.”

Comment: *the changing of a character's race (even in alternate universes) seems to be less of a thing in superhero comics*... ummm, nope on the contrary. There's a black Superman, Asian Batman and even WW has been presented to be of different race in the comics.

Comment: There's a difference between "less of a thing" and "not a thing at all". We do occasionally see race-switching comics, but it tends to be less common proportionally than it is in other media. Bear in mind that there _many_ more versions of Superman, Wonder Woman, Luthor, etc, in comics, than there are in other media. Based on sheer volume of output alone, you can expect to see _some_ race-switching in comics, even if it happens less often, proportionally speaking, than it does elsewhere. This is especially true if you compare comics to live-action movies/shows.